# Unable to print desired output while practicing getters setters

Tags: java

Besides the get and set method, I created a method called printAllDetails with the purpose to print out details of every registrant. There are 3 registrants with each of their respective names and ages.

```
public class BASIC_GettersSetters {

String name;
int age;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    BASIC_GettersSetters a = new BASIC_GettersSetters(); // Assume BASIC_GettersSetters is Account
    
    a.setName("Kim Hyun Jin");
    a.setAge(32);
    System.out.println(a.getName());
    System.out.println(a.getAge());
    
    a.setName("Kang Jeon Il");
    a.setAge(32);
    System.out.println(a.getName());
    System.out.println(a.getAge());
    
    a.setName("Choi Jin Woo");
    a.setAge(30);
    System.out.println(a.getName());
    System.out.println(a.getAge());
    
    a.printAllDetails();
    
}
```

The method is right at the bottom. When I pressed the F6 key to run the program, it only shows the last registrant; Choi Jin Woo, 30. So I'm confused right there. Should I use array? But then, how do I apply it together with get and set methods? Or should I use something else that I don't know of?

```
    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
}

public void printAllDetails () {
    System.out.println("Registrants : " + getName() + " // " + getAge());
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated. Thank you. - Coding noob

Comment: You are only creating *one* `BASIC_GettersSetters` instance, of which you change the name and age constantly.

Comment: you are basically reassigning the values, use arraylist or something similar, then append the values to it

Comment: In order to create 3 registrants, create 3 objects (so three times `new BASIC_GettersSetters()`)

Comment: But you'd also need to call `print` on each of the 3 objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating one instance of `BASIC_GettersSetters` and repeatedly changing the values. So when you call `printAllDetails` it's printing the last set of values.

You want to create separate instances:

```
BASIC_GettersSetters a = new BASIC_GettersSetters(); 
a.setName("Kim Hyun Jin");
a.setAge(32);
System.out.println(a.getName());
System.out.println(a.getAge());

BASIC_GettersSetters b = new BASIC_GettersSetters(); 
b.setName("Kang Jeon Il");
b.setAge(32);
System.out.println(b.getName());
System.out.println(b.getAge());

BASIC_GettersSetters c = new BASIC_GettersSetters(); 
c.setName("Choi Jin Woo");
c.setAge(30);
System.out.println(c.getName());
System.out.println(c.getAge());

a.printAllDetails();
b.printAllDetails();
c.printAllDetails();
```

You should also consider renaming `BASIC_GettersSetters()` to something more meaningful.

Comment: Understood. So I need to create separate instances to keep track of registrants in this case. Thank you 

Answer (score 2):

You create only one object (`new BASIC_GettersSetters()`). If you call the setter on the same object multiple times, you overwrite the previously set value.

First, you should name your classes properly. I suggest renaming your `BASIC_GettersSetters` to `Registrant`. Second, you should create as many `Registrant` objects as needed (in your case, three).